# What insect would make a hole and lay eggs in it

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Does anyone here have an idea what insect would make a 1-2mm hole in a grape vine cane, and lay small white/clear eggs?

[image]

Holes in cane:

[image: 1.5mm eggs]

Comment: What's your location?